# Can I style the Desing Library Snackbar through styles.xml

Tags: android

I would like to reduce boilerplate setting up Snackbar colors in my code. Can I style it overriding an existing style, for example?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `Snackbar` using a few common items with other widgets (like `colorAccent`), so just changing those was problematic for me too. Instead I added my own `design_layout_snackbar_include.xml`. Take the [original](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/layout/design_layout_snackbar_include.xml)  and modify what you will need. It will work for all of your snackbars.